# How do I constrain variables to a user-defined domain in ArgMax?

Tags: functions, variable-definitions, expression-manipulation

I am trying to `ArgMax` a function over `x`, but `x` is only defined between `[0,1]`

How do I do that? I have tried:

```
ArgMax[f1[x], x ∈ [0,1]]
```

But it gave me an error.
 "{x}[Element]" cannot be followed by "[0,1]".

Comment: doesn't `ArgMax[{f1[x],0<x<1},x]` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the new (in **V10**) `ImplicitRegion` function as follows:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1, {x}];
```

Then:

```
ArgMax[f1[x], x ∈ reg]
```